# Python: Convert Dictionary of String Times to Date Times

Tags: python, django, string, dictionary, time

I have a dictionary `alerts[]` which includes the key `alert_date`. All dates/times are stored as strings. I am displaying the date in Django, but templates can't format time stored as a sting. So, I want to convert it in my view as such:

```
foo = "2014-10-07 00:00:00"
bar = datetime.strptime(foo, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But, I want to convert all the dictionary time values at once. I'm grabbing the dictionary as JSON through an API call. I want to do something like this (which is obviously invalid code):

```
alerts = resp_data['alerts']
for v in alerts['alert_date']:
    v = datetime.strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

//EDIT:
The JSON response is a dictionary which contains `alerts`, which is a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
{"alerts": [
    {
      "key1": "value11",
      "key2": "value12",
      "key3": "value13",
      "alert_date": "2014-06-05 01:00:23.633000",
    },
    {
      "key1": "value21",
      "key2": "value22",
      "key3": "value23",
      "alert_date": "2010-12-31 00:00:00",
    }
]}
```

Comment: please post also the exact content of the alerts variable. You can replace the values, but I need to understand what it really contains

Comment: @Apero I didn't state that this was a list of dictionaries. Question updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
now that you have added some sample json response data, I know that this answer is correct, `alerts` **IS a list of dicts**:

From your example, I now assume that:

- `alerts` is a list of `alert` dictionaries
- `alert['alert_date']` is a date string

Therefore I would suggest you to do:

```
alerts = resp_data['alerts']
for alert in alerts:
    alert['alert_date'] = datetime.strptime(alert['alert_date'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I had to change that 2nd line to `for alert in alerts:`, but otherwise it worked. Thanks!

Comment: As @Kasramvd mentioned, my strptime example is expecting a specific format. That is not met in my sample data ("2014-06-05 01:00:23.633000" ). I also had to switch data sources to one with consistent time formatting for this to work.

Comment: yes, data source integrity and uniformity is the most important. You can of course put a try / except inside this loop.

Comment: You could also use this http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html. Just be careful and set the dayfirst or yearfirst options

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {datetime.strptime(key, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"): val for key, val in alerts['alert_date'].items()}
```

Also note that, since you are using `datetime.strptime` with an specified format it might raise a `ValueError`. Which in that case the dict-comprehension won't be helpful. So if you are not sure about the fromat of your dates you need to handle the exceptions:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in alerts['alert_date'].items():
    try:
        new_dict[datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")] = v 
    except ValueError:
        new_dict[datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")] = '' # or what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wanted to just change the date strings in the `alerts` list dictionaries and leave the other keys/values untouched. I would suggest the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
alerts = map(lambda x: dict(x, **{'alert_date': datetime.strptime(x['alert_date'], fmt)}), alerts)
```

If your date string format is inconsistent, like in your JSON Response example, you could drop the microsecond part by executing `split()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert(s):
    s = s.split('.')[0]
    return datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

alerts = map(lambda x: dict(x, **{'alert_date': convert(x['alert_date'])}), alerts)
```

The resulting `alerts` lists for both examples look like this:

```
[{'alert_date': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 5, 1, 0, 23),
  'key1': 'value11',
  'key2': 'value12',
  'key3': 'value13'},
 {'alert_date': datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 31, 0, 0),
  'key1': 'value21',
  'key2': 'value22',
  'key3': 'value23'}]
```

Comment: i like your approach, but i think it's kind of the opposite. They have a date object on a dict and wants to convert this date object to a string

Comment: i would suggest to use isinstance() to check if the value is a date object instead of having the key name hard coded

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did something like this

On my case, the dict may have date object, or not

And I don't know the key of the date/datetime field

```
def convert_date_on_dict(old_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in old_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, (date, datetime)):
            new_dict[k] = v.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        else:
            new_dict[k] = v

    return new_dict
```

So...

```
for item in myDictList:
    new_item = convert_date_on_dict(item)
```